# No file or variants found for asset: assets/images

Tags: flutter, dart

loginpage.dart

```
 child: Column(children: [Image.asset("assets/images/loginimage.png")],),
```

assets file are

```
 assets:
    - assets/images
         # - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
```

error is

Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
No file or variants found for asset: assets/images.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 42s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       289.8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Do you have a folder named `assets/images` and do you have an image file named `loginimage.png` in it in your project folder?

Comment: @Sisir Yes I have

Comment: Can you cross check the name of the folders and the name of the image file and the file extension is .png and nothing else. Your error seems related to this only

Comment: post your pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Check the spaces. Generally, it should have three spaces from the start of the new line.

assets:

- assets/images //make sure it has three spaces

Answer (score 0):

Can you try edit your pubspec.yaml file like this.

```
assets:
- assets/images/
```

Answer (score 0):

The pubspec.yaml file is the issue. Make this change.

```
assets:
  - assets/images/
```

**NOTE:** Spaces in .yaml file is **VERY** important. make sure your .yaml looks like this.

There may be less files, but the spaces are to be noted
[image]